# How to pass intent to methodchannel in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

I want to pass webpage url to my app by using methodchannel, but my methodchannel always returns 'null'.

I followed the official document, which is [How do I handle incoming intents from external applications in Flutter?](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-intent-in-flutter) , and this is my code .

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
      android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
      />
    <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
      android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
      />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  private String sharedText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
      if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
      }
    }

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "app.channel.shared").setMethodCallHandler(
      new MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, MethodChannel.Result result) {
          if (call.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
            result.success(sharedText);
            sharedText = null;
          }
        }
      });
  }

  void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  String url;

  static const channel = const MethodChannel('app.channel.shared');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    setState(() {
      url = "sample";
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      getChannel();
    }
  }

  void getChannel() async {
    var message = await channel.invokeMethod("getSharedText");
    debugPrint(message);
    setState(() {
      url = message;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(url),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to get data in `channel.invokeMethod("getSharedText");`, but it returns `null`.

Are there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to return testing value at the place of result.success(sharedText);. if its working then add logs inside handleSendText with this code
log.d("RequiredVal" + sharedText).
then find this value in logs. maybe sharedText is null.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tested my code, and maybe I found the problem.
The problem was that Intent action was MAIN_ACTION, not SEND_ACTION.
However, I don't know why it was MAIN ACTION. Do you have any idea?